# Which one is fastest in C: fabsf(-3) or (-1)*(-3)?

Tags: c, optimization, normalization

Which one is fastest in C to do the L1-norm?

```
float x = fabsf(-3.0f);
```

or

```
float x = -1.0f * (-3.0f);
```

?

Both return the number `x = 3`

Comment: They are probably both evaluated at compile time and produce the same assembly code, equivalent to `float x = 3.0f;`.  That may happen even without any optimization; add optimization, and it's almost certain.  And even if there was a difference, it would almost certainly be unmeasurable.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: C is only an abstract programming language, so it does not have a feature of how long computations take. By and large, the C standard specifies the results of computations, not the times they take. How long something takes to compute is a feature of a specific C implementation in specific circumstances. An optimizing compiler will produce the same result for `float x = fabsf(-3.0f);` and `float x = -1.0f * (-3.0f);`, which is to evaluate the initializer at compile time and produce identical object file output that initializes `x` to 3 without doing any arithmetic at execution time.

Comment: If your code was an overly simplified example for an L1-norm that will be computed at run-time, then you need to give more information. For one thing, an L1 norm cannot be computed merely by multiplying by −1; one would have to decide whether or not to multiply, based on the sign of the data. Factors that affect performance include compiler, compiler switches, target processor model, number of elements to be processed, features of the surrounding code, operating system workload, memory system characteristics, and more.

Comment: To perform a large number of `fabsf` operations, it is often fast to AND or AND-NOT data using SIMD instructions with a prepared mask. This generally should be combined with other operations when possible.

Comment: @euraad "L1-norm" deserves a reference.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes. I agree!

Comment: If you know x is negative, x = -x might be faster. Let the compiler decide how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on the library used.

Some use the x86 instruction "[fabs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fabs)" as in [Apple's fabfs implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-47.1/ppc.subproj/fabs.c.auto.html):

```
#define __FABSF(x) \
({ \
    float __value, __arg = (x); \
    asm volatile ("fabs %0,%1" : "=f" (__value): "f" (__arg)); \
    __value; \
})
```

just clear the negative bit using a bitmask, [as in](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10318742/)

```
float fabsf(const float x) _MATH_REENTRANT
{
    FS_STATIC union float_long fl;

    fl.f = x;
    fl.l &= 0x7fffffff;
    return fl.f;
}
```

or [ReactOS](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d0/de7/fabsf_8c.html)

```
{
    /* Load the value as uint */
    unsigned int u32 = *(unsigned int*)&x;
 
    /* Clear the sign bit */
    u32 &= ~(1 << 31);
 
    /* Check for NAN */
    if (u32 > 0x7F800000)
    {
        /* Set error bit */
        *(unsigned int*)&x |= 0x00400000;
        return x;
    }
 
    /* Convert back to float */
    return *(float*)&u32;
}
```

and no doubt some multiply by -1.

so you'll have to write your own benchmark and tell us!

Comment: _"some multiply by -1"_ - That wouldn't be a very good `fabsf` function when used with positive values. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Nope =)

Comment: `*(unsigned int*)&x |= 0x00400000;` risks aliasing and better avoided.  Use the `union` approach.

Comment: gbjbaanb, `1 << 31` leads to UB.  Better as `1u << 31` and `uint32_t u32`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was referencing the OP's own question ;)

Comment: @gbjbaanb Since it was a list of different library implementations I read it like this: _"depends on the library used [...] and no doubt some multiply by -1"_ which I doubt anyone does :-)